# Horizontal SlideUp SlideDown with Scriptaculous

Tags: scriptaculous, slideup, slidedown

You may know the [scriptaculous SlideUp effect](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-slideup).
Well, It slides up a div vertically as a closing effect.

I would like to make it work horizontal. There is an option for this : scaleX:true, scaleY:false

But it doesn't work fine : the div jumps down before closing...

Does anyone know how to use the slideUp effect for horizontal sliding ?

Thanks

Comment: use jquery animation :D... sorry, no idea about scriptaculous

Comment: Yes, I should have a closer look to jQuery, it seems to be a nice library.
But this horizontal slide is the final touch of my current project, and I would need to find the solution with Scriptaculous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any built in scriptaculous effects which accomplish this, but is fairly easy to build a custom combination effect that does just what you ask.

Here is a gist of code I use: http://gist.github.com/374478

It is just slightly modified versions of the built in SlideDown / SlideUp so that they become SlideRight / SlideLeft.